# Как узнать включен ли у меня proguard?

Tags: android-studio

Дело в том, что в моём проекте есть несколько текстовых файлов, название которых  proguard-rules (для самого приложения и библиотеки). В gradle файле

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Означает ли это то, что proguard включен и какая у него тут функция?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обфускация отключена из-за того что minifyEnabled выставлено в false, переключите в true, и пересоздайте apk. Для убедительности можете взять собранный apk, открыть в какой нибудь утилите просмотра исходников, и убедиться в обфускации кода

Comment: `minifyEnabled false` прогвард **выключен**. Или я не прав?

Comment: @pavel, Да, вы правы, совершенно верно, его то не приметил, minifyEnabled нужно переводить в true